# Angular Expression Interpolation

Tags: angularjs, interpolation

I came through the following example of ng-class="expression" in a book.
http://plnkr.co/edit/fJGT5L9HZXvgAiAyXwlW?p=preview

```
ng-class="{error:isError,warning:isWarning}"
```

I get the controller logic, but my doubt is in the interpolation happening here.

What does the following scenarios mean (what is the evaluated value) and **Why**?

1. ng-class="{error:true,warning:true}"
2. ng-class="{error:true,warning:false}"
3. ng-class="{error:false,warning:true}"
4. ng-class="{error:false,warning:false}"

Comment: CSS classes will be set based on condition. If `isError` is true the error class will be added. And no interpolation is happening here. You are passing JSON TO `ngClass`

Answer (score 2):

1. ng-class="{error:true,warning:true}" **=>** class="error warning"
2. ng-class="{error:true,warning:false}" **=>** class="error"
3. ng-class="{error:false,warning:true}" **=>** class="warning"
4. ng-class="{error:false,warning:false}" **=>** no classes set

As you could notice ng-class get just hash where keys are names of classes and values -- conditions (if true than class will be added to `class` attribute)

So, `ng-class` just uses angular expression and check what data it returns (string, array or hash-map) then it applies certain parser to get final classes array to put it to `class`. One of this is described above.

### Angular expressions

Angular like as Javascript uses eval mechanism to execute code (expression), but unlike JS Angular uses safe eval called `$eval([expression], [locals])` ([Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval))

I'm strongly recommending you to read this [article](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) about Angular expressions to understand how it works.

Comment: nice, but some explanation would probably help author of question :)

Comment: Thanks Max for the reply, and Jarema for getting my point :). I can see in the HTML but my doubt is how the object {error:true || false,warning: true || false} gets evaluated and gets assigned. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) arguments docs:

> The result of the arguments evaluation can be a string
>   representing space delimited class names, an array, or a map of class
>   names to boolean values. In the case of a map, the names of the
>   properties whose values are truthy will be added as css classes to the
>   element.

So in your case the result of the arguments after evaluation is a map which produces:

```
ng-class="{error:true,warning:true}"
=> class="error warning"

ng-class="{error:true,warning:false}"
=> class="error"

ng-class="{error:false,warning:true}"
=> class="warning"

ng-class="{error:false,warning:false}"
=> no class attribute
```

Comment: Thanks Catalin. It helped me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Angular will add (or append to the existing class attr) the following class attribute to the element:

1. class="error warning"
2. class="error"
3. class="warning"
4. No class attribute added